# Can any one explain in which case we use PowerMockito.when() and PowerMockito.doReturn()

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, powermockito

I was writing test case for my service class but i m not sure when to use `PowerMockito.when()` and `PowerMockito.doReturn()` as both behavior looks similar to me.

Comment: One uses PowerMockito when one cannot use Mockito. See [Mockito's FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ) for details. But be warned that PowerMockito does bytecode manipulation and may cause trouble in conjunction with oter tool utilizing bytecode manipulation, e.g. JaCoCo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding  doReturn() and when() are almost equal ,but the difference which i found in when() type-checking of the value that you're returning at compile time where as
in doReturn() there is no type-checking of the value that you're returning at compile time

For Example:

**case1:**

```
PowerMockito.when(mongoTamplate.getCollection(Mockito.eq("testdoc"))).thenReturn(mongoCollection);
```

**case2:**

```
powerMockito.doReturn(mongoCollection).when(mongoTamplate).getCollection(Mockito.eq("test-doc"))
```

In case 1 type of mongoCollection is checked at compile time where as in case2 type of mongoCollection  is not checked at compilation

Comment: One is forced to use `doReturn(...)` or `doThrow(...)` if one tires to mock the call to a method with `void` return type (those do not work with `when(...)`).